# Indestructible armor vs indestructible projectiles

Tags: internal-consistency, materials

So in my story I have a super material that is lightweight, nearly indestructible, and conducts vibration, heat, electricity and any other energy across its surface but not through its center.

My question is simple. What would happen to armor made of this material if you shot high velocity bullets made of the same material at it? If neither deforms or shatters, what do they do?

Comment: *"Conducts [...] energy across it's surface":* conducts it where? Energy (and momentum! never forget momentum, it's a vector quantity!) never really goes away. Reality check: when a medieval low-velocity iron cannonball hits a solider's armor made of ordinary poor quality steel neither the cannonball nor the armor shatter or deform significantly; yet the soldier still dies of blunt force trauma -- because the *armor* hits him.

Comment: This depends entirely upon the material properties of your nearly indestructible material. What exactly do you means by conducts vibrations?

Comment: This is entirely up to you unless you want to provide us with the material characteristics of your fictional material.  Generally speaking, a material can always be used to pierce itself.  Is if flexible?  Malleable? Brittle? this an other information would detrmine whether it tears, cracks, or shatters.

Comment: @AlexP Can you cite a source to back up the claim that medieval armor wouldn't deform when shot by a cannon?

Comment: @sphennings: It's a fictional "low-velocity" cannonball; initially I wanted to say a war mace hitting a helmet, which is more realistic but (I thought) less colorful. It's a thought experiment, intendended to explain that even if the armor doesn't deform, all it can do is *distribute* the impact over a larger surface, it cannot poof it out of existence.

Comment: It would undergo elastic deformation upon getting hit. As far as conducting electricity and vibration, think Captain America's shield. It will only conduct along the surface, so if you're holding a shield made of it and it gets struck, most of the energy will dissipate by radiating out from the edges of the shield. If that makes sense.

Comment: @AlexP Perhaps it would have been better to talk about being hit with a sledgehammer then. Though I'm pretty sure if you hit a breastplate with a 20lbs hammer it would deform significantly.

Comment: @AlexP  The cannonball example made me think of the 3 collisions in a car crash.  Car collides with object, driver collides with inside of car, organs collide with inside of chest cavity.

Comment: @AlexP I presume that would be the case because medieval iron would be fairly inelastic. Result: Good night, knight, undone by your own armour.

Comment: Neither deforms upon impact?  The bullet stops instantly?  Einstein won't like that--the "stop!" signal can only propagate at lightspeed.  The bullet both stops instantly and doesn't stop instantly--you just created a paradox.  The cosmic censors come along and shoot you as part of stamping out all traces of this invention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, Sir Isaac Newton will always have his say.  The Energy has to go somewhere.

Given that your material qualifies as *handwavium* or *unobtanium*  we're going to skip over the the detailed math and just get down to some wild assumptions.

You state that neither projectile nor shield will deform on impact.  This is going to be a nearly perfectly [Elastic Collision](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/elacol.html).  So if we assume that the Shield is perfectly stationary and the slug is moving at a given velocity, all of the momentum of the slug is going to be transferred into the shield.  Think of [Newton's Cradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cradle).

Your bullet is going to have a certain amount of [Muzzle Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzzle_energy) .  Bullets do a lot of damage because all of that energy impacts on a very small space, tearing through tissue and bone.  If the bullet impacts the shield, all of that energy will be dissipated over the surface of the shield.

Of course now the shield will have all that energy which will then need to be dissipated lest it get concentrated into the relatively small points where the shield is being held.   This is where some padding with plenty of give will be useful.

Of course something has to happen to the bullet.  If it is a direct hit, it will simply stop and fall to the ground.  Otherwise it will deflect and carry on, with some of the momentum carrying through the shield.

Other minor things to consider.  Ordinary bullets lose energy when they deform.  Body armor works by spreading the energy of a bullet out over a larger area, preventing penetration.  If you get shot and are wearing body armor, you still get hit with the same amount of energy, even if the round does not penetrate.

Answer (score 1):

Your bullet would be stopped without penetrating.

Your target would be hit by the kinetic force of the bullet over a wide area with or without being killed or hurt depending on the padding, shape, angle of the hit, dangerous objects they may hit as they're pushed back.

Your target may have a fatal heart attack or at the very least experience some mental trauma and get a hell of a scare.